# Vue: attaching @keyup/@input event to data property breaks form input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to attach a simple character counter to an input element but the second I display it back to the user, the input breaks in that I'm unable to enter any additional characters in the input box.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <label class="label" :class="{ 'label-large' : large }" v-if="label">
            {{ label }} <sup class="is-required" v-if="isRequired">Req</sup>
        </label>
        <input class="input-control" :class="{ 'input-large' : large }" :maxlength="maxLength" :placeholder="placeholderText" ref="input" :value="text" @change="formatValue($event.target.value)" @keyup="countCharacters($event.target.value)" />
        <div class="flex text-x-small-regular mt-2" :class="large ? 'px-4' : 'px-2'" v-if="maxLength || validationFailed">
            <div class="validation-message">
                <template v-if="validationFailed">{{ validationMessage }}</template>
            </div>
            <div class="character-count" v-if="maxLength">
                <span :class="characterCountWarningStyle">{{ characterCount }}</span> / {{ maxLength }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        isRequired: {
            default: false,
            required: false,
            type: Boolean
        },
        label: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
        large: {
            default: false,
            required: false,
            type: Boolean,
        },
        maxLength: {
            required: false,
            type: Number
        },
        placeholder: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
        text: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
        validationMessage: {
            default: "Required field.",
            required: false,
            type: String
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            characterCount: 0,
            validationFailed: false,
            value: undefined
        }
    },
    computed: {
        characterCountWarningStyle() {
            return "" // Simplified.
        },
        placeholderText() {
            return "" // Simplified.
        }
    },
    methods: {
        countCharacters(value) {
            // Works: 
            console.log(value.length);
            // Breaks form input: this.characterCount = value.length;
        },
        formatValue(value) {
            this.validationFailed = false;

            if (value) value = value.trim();

            this.validate(value);
        },
        validate(value) {
            if (this.isRequired && !value) {
                this.validationFailed = true;
            }

            this.$emit('update', value);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

To summarize the code above, I'm doing some basic cleansing on change, and am looking to trigger a character count on key up. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Could you update [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hud9ytL/) so that it demonstrates the issue?

Comment: It's so weird. As soon as I remove :value="text" from the HTML it works fine, but the second I add the binding it starts blocking all input. I'm using Vue 2.6, by the way.

Comment: Actually try here: https://jsfiddle.net/r46g3nt1/

Comment: You are mutating props. That's where you should begin..

Comment: Sorry how? I’ve tried it with a computed setter too. Same issue.

Comment: I didn't say that it fixes your issue. Just a mistake. You can fix your issue when you replace `:value` with `v-model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `characterCount` update in the `keyup` handler is triggering a rerender of the entire component in order to render the new value of the `characterCount` string interpolation in the template. The rendering includes the `<input>`, whose value is bound to `text`. If `text` is an empty string or null, the `<input>` is effectively cleared on `keyup`.

To resolve the issue, use a local copy of the `text` prop that can be modified, and bind it to the `<input>`'s `v-model`.

1. Create a data property (named `"value"`), and a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the `text` prop that copies `text` into `value`:

   ```js
   export default {
     props: {
       text: {/*...*/},
     },
     data() {
       return {
         value: ''
       }
     },
     watch: {
       text(newText) {
         this.value = newText
       }
     },
   }
   ```
2. Use the new `value` property as the `<input>`'s [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model):

   ```html
   <input v-model="value">
   ```
3. Remove the `keyup` handler and the `characterCount` data property, and instead use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that returns the length of `value`:

   ```js
   export default {
     computed: {
       characterCount() {
         return this.value.length
       }
     },
   }
   ```

[image: Edit Troubleshooting input changes]

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `:value` with `v-model` for a two way data binding, and instead of mutating the `text` prop directly, add a local property (e.g. `localText`). I'd also use a `computed` property to calculate the length instead of an event for better readability. So, something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label class="label" :class="{ 'label-large' : large }" v-if="label">
            {{ label }} <sup class="is-required" v-if="isRequired">Req</sup>
        </label>
        <input class="input-control" :class="{ 'input-large' : large }" :maxlength="maxLength" :placeholder="placeholderText" ref="input" v-model="localText" @change="formatValue($event.target.value)" />
        <div class="flex text-x-small-regular mt-2" :class="large ? 'px-4' : 'px-2'" v-if="maxLength || validationFailed">
            <div class="validation-message">
                <template v-if="validationFailed">{{ validationMessage }}</template>
            </div>
            <div class="character-count" v-if="maxLength">
                <span :class="characterCountWarningStyle">{{ characterCount }}</span> / {{ maxLength }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        isRequired: {
            default: false,
            required: false,
            type: Boolean
        },
        label: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
        large: {
            default: false,
            required: false,
            type: Boolean,
        },
        maxLength: {
            required: false,
            default: 10,
            type: Number
        },
        placeholder: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
        text: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
        validationMessage: {
            default: "Required field.",
            required: false,
            type: String
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            localText: this.text || '',
            validationFailed: false,
            value: undefined
        }
    },
    computed: {
        characterCount() {
            return this.localText.length;
        },
        characterCountWarningStyle() {
            return "" // Simplified.
        },
        placeholderText() {
            return "" // Simplified.
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formatValue(value) {
            this.validationFailed = false;

            if (value) value = value.trim();

            this.validate(value);
        },
        validate(value) {
            if (this.isRequired && !value) {
                this.validationFailed = true;
            }

            this.$emit('update', value);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```